Did Thales of Miletus have any prior or external philosophical influences?
Thales of Miletus is often creditedcitation needed  with having been the earliest known/recorded Founder of (Western) Philosophy and Science.  He was reportedcitation needed  to have accurately forecasted a solar eclipse-(with no available advanced technologies), as well as to found-(or establish) the first major lement....Water. 2600 years ago, Thales founded his own philosophical and scientific school in Western Anatolia-(present-day Western Turkey) and would go on to influence and impact the legacy of Greek Philosophy and Hellenistic Science centuries latercitation needed .
Yet, despite these accolades and accomplishments, did Thales have any significant prior philosophical and/or scientific influences from cultures, such as the Egyptians, the Babylonians (or from elsewhere)? Is there a corpus of historical literature which may be able to
document and chronicle the earliest influences of Thales of Miletus? Unfortunately, there is scarce textual information on Thales-(even dating to the Greek sources); though perhaps there might be some suggestions and leads that one may recommend in better understanding the influences and intellectual origins of this important figure in the History of Ideas.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s).

I'm not sure that much can be added to the (well-sourced) Wikipedia article on Thales. The answer is unclear and disputed by scholars.

As you notice yourself, all information about Thales that we possess comes from much later Hellenistic sources. Many of them say things incredible or very imprecise. What does it mean, for example that he "predicted a solar eclipse"? With what accuracy? With what certainty? How long in advance? Modern historians tend to think that he could only predict the year in which the eclipse will likely occur. So we don't know what exactly Thales discovered, only what later legends credit to him.
Same sources mention that he traveled in Egypt and studied
with Egyptian priests. However they do not specify what exactly he could learn from those Egyptian priests. What we know about science in Egypt at that time indicates that there was nothing for him to learn there. None of the Hellenistic sources mention that he learned anything from Babylon.
So we just don't know.

Good answer.....many thanks.
